# How to set/get various alpha values to RichTextBox content at random locations

Tags: c#, .net

Let me make a confession first , I am newbie to C# and .Net :)

I have a set of RichTextBoxs , content in the box can be applied different colors at substring level, like this , 
 this.selectedField.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.FromArgb(253, Color.Black);

when I try to read the Alpha value for that part of string , using (Color clr = this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor;) clr.A always gives 255 , full opacity.

Is it anyway possible to assign and retirve the same value I assign ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, the RichTextBox doesn't support the Alpha Channel. So you can set it (because the Color object supports it), but it will be ignored by the RichTextBox and so always be set to full opacity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Then I think I have to findsome other alternative.